# How can I get rid of the unwanted space between a Java JTextField and a JLabel using the GridBagLayout

Tags: java, jlabel, jtextfield, gridbaglayout

With the Java GridBagLayout why is there a large space to the right of the first JTextField (Labeled A) before the column but the last two JTextField's B and C behave as expected without unwanted spaces between them and how can I eliminate the space?
I've attached an image below to show the problem along with the code.

```
    /* Label digital timer */
    gbcRightPanel.gridx = 0;
    gbcRightPanel.gridy = 0;
    rightPanel.add(labelDitigalTimer, gbcRightPanel);

    /* Text Field Hours */
    gbcRightPanel.gridx = 0;
    gbcRightPanel.gridy = 1;
    gbcRightPanel.weighty = 1;
    rightPanel.add(jtxtFieldHours, gbcRightPanel);

    /* Label colon */
    gbcRightPanel.gridx = 1;
    gbcRightPanel.gridy = 1;
    rightPanel.add(new JLabel(":"), gbcRightPanel);

    /* Text Field Minuites */
    gbcRightPanel.gridx = 2;
    gbcRightPanel.gridy = 1;
    rightPanel.add(jtxtFieldMinuites, gbcRightPanel);

    /*Colon*/
    gbcRightPanel.gridx = 3;
    gbcRightPanel.gridy = 1;
    rightPanel.add(new JLabel(":"), gbcRightPanel);

    /* Text Field Seconds */
    gbcRightPanel.gridx = 4;
    gbcRightPanel.gridy = 1;
    rightPanel.add(jtxtFieldSeconds, gbcRightPanel);
```

[image: Image of the right panel with space problem]

Comment: Post a valid [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) if the answer does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `GridBagLayout` works with cells consisting of row/columns.

The first row has a single column. The second row has 5 columns.

So the width of column 1 is the width of the largest component in all the rows of the first column which happens to be your label so you see the extra space.

One way to change this is to have the label take up 5 columns. So before you add the label you need to use:

```
gbcRightPane.gridWidth = 5;
rightPanel.add(labelDitigalTimer, gbcRightPanel);
gbcRightPane.gridWidth = 1; // reset for the other components.
```

Now the label will appear above all 5 of the components. You can then determine whether you want the label centered or left justified by specifying an appropriate constraint.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information about the constraints and working examples.

Another approach is to use nested panels. So you can create a separate panel for the text fields and colon labels. Then in the GridBagPanel you add the label and the panel as two separate components.

Read up on the other layout managers from the tutorial to get an idea how each layout manager works to you can effectively nest panels to get the desired layout.

Comment: Your solution to set the gridwidth of the label to 5 and to reset the gridwidth for the other components works. 

How does the first row have a single column and the second has 5? Or do you mean that the gridWidth that is set for the first row will dictate the width of any subsequent rows that are created? Or were you referring to my specific case?

Comment: @FlashspeedIfe, With the suggested solution, the first row has a single component that spans the width of the first 5 columns of the second row. Since there are only 5 components on the second row, the component on the first row, spans all the components on the second row. Read the tutorial and play with the example code.

Answer (score 0):

```
gbcRightPanel.weighty = 1;
```

Makes the panel have a multiplicator / weigth of 1.0, so any space on x-axis which is left over after all other elements have been placed, go to the first column.

Try to add an fourth column and give this column a bigger weight.